# How to have ajax call and use of RestFul webservice in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, ajax, cross-domain

Well i have studied the angular js document and this code works perfect on the same server; somehow not working on cross site; localhost is reachable

```
module='user';
siteurl='http://localhost/angularjs';
url=siteurl+"/admin/"+module+"/list";
BlockUi();
$http({
        url     :   url,
        method  :   "post",
        data    :   "",
        headers : {'Content-Type':undefined}

    }).then(function(responseText){
        $scope.totaltablerows=responseText.data.response_data;
        $scope.tablerows=$scope.totaltablerows;
        UnblockUi();
        $scope.searchFunction();

    },function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        UnblockUi();
        UnknownError();
    });
```

What should i do so that this could work.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the port after localhost ?

Comment: i tried it to? thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your localhost is where your backend is also running, there is no need to explicitly mention that, so you code would look like:

```
BlockUi();
$http({
        url     :  "/admin/user/list",
        method  :   "post",
        data    :   "",
        headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

    }).then(function(responseText){
        $scope.totaltablerows=responseText.data.response_data;
        $scope.tablerows=$scope.totaltablerows;
        UnblockUi();
        $scope.searchFunction();

    },function(error){
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        UnblockUi();
        UnknownError();
    });
```

You do not need to mention the `'http://localhost/angularjs'`  at the beginning of the URL, also, why are you setting the `content-type` to `undefined`

Comment: yup, but you can call it from out of the server; what about that, and content-type:undefined means you can pass the data that may or may not be in json format